# Which version does my custom intellij plugin support for Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am writing a custom plugin for IntelliJ.

But how can I know which IntelliJ version my custom plugin supports. 
And my custom plugin support which version of Android Studio.

Testing every version Android Studio may work, but any better idea to get my plugin supporting Android Studio version.

Comment: You can specify build numbers range for your plugin:
http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/build_number_ranges.html But to make sure that your plugin actually works as intended, testing is necessary for each IDE version.

Comment: If it *builds* on multiple versions of the IntelliJ SDK, chances are that it will also *run* correctly. But @Argb32 is right, in theory you have to test your plugin to check if it works correctly.

Comment: you can use gradle to build, it will download the corresponding sdk source for you https://github.com/zhengjunbase/codehelper.generator/tree/develop
in the build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [Android Studio <-> IDEA Tags](http://tools.android.com/build/studio/idea-tags). You can find the relationship of version between intellij idea and android stdio.